# Cannot read property 'uid' of null when logout

Tags: firebase, ionic4

Every time I logout from my app, I get

> Cannot read property 'uid' of null

from console. it leads reference to below code:

```
constructor( private firestore: AngularFirestore, private auth: AuthService, ) 
{
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (this.currentUser == user) {
    this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.vendor = firebase.firestore().doc(`/Products/${this.currentUser.uid}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

This is useless because its already the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onAuthStateChanged` callback will fire whenever the user's authentication state changes, so whenever they sign in, or they're signed out. In the latter case, the `user` will be `null`, which you don't handle correctly in your code right now.

This looks more correct:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (this.currentUser) {
    this.vendor = firebase.firestore().doc(`/Products/${this.currentUser.uid}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use uid for optional chaining

```
firebase.firestore().doc(`/Products/${this.currentUser?.uid}`)
```

or another solution is when you logout from the system set current user is null or empty object

```
setCurrentUser({})
```